# Is there some book about how to design a 3D math lib?

Tags: algorithm, performance

3D math covers vector algebra and matrix algebra, which are easily calculated on paper, but not so easy when coding them effectively. I only leant some basic algorithms on matrix in my Data Structure course, which is not enough when it comes to accurate and effective operations.

Is there some books on this topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [current consensus](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/146/16) seems to be that asking for literature (or similar) recommendations is not a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 3):

Books: http://www.essentialmath.com/book.htm is the one.

Best algos on the real 3D topics (and some tricky 2D like image resize and premult-alpha ), explained and with source most of the time.

The website is very nice too, the "tutorial" full of gems

Adding http://www.geometrictools.com/index.html which is the most complete source code repository on the topic, with loads of very precise algos implemented.

Comment: It's the book. :-)